# newterm using the ncurses crate

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm using the `ncurses-rs` crate and I'm having issues figuring out what should I pass to the `newterm()` call. From the very obscure documentation I was able to find, I think it expects an optional termtype to be used in place of `$TERM`, along with two file descriptors for stdout and stdin. However, I'm not sure how should I do this since I'm not familiar with mixing thinly wrapped C types with Rust types. I have tried to pass `None, std::io::stdout().as_raw_fd(), std::io::stdin().as_raw_fd()`, but that did not work - the compiler says it wants a `*-ptr`.

[Here is the source](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L1030-L1039).

Comment: Looks like it expects a libc `FILE` struct pointer. You might be able to create one from the file descriptors with the corresponding libc function (like `open`, for example).